# ¿Como valido, con laravel, que un campo sea solo numerico?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

he intentado con lo que aparece en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-numeric) de laravel, pero no me sirva

este es mi codigo:

```
'cedula' =>  'numeric|required|unique:personas|min:6|max:8',
```

de esta manera, si coloco letras, me dice: "cedula debe ser numérico."

y si coloco numeros me dice que no debe ser mayor a 8, cuando siquiera coloco 3 numeros.

no entiendo el porque :/

Comment: Ese es el comportamiento normal de dichas validaciones, ¿qué quieres lograr? ¿puedes dar un ejemplo práctico de valores permitidos?

Comment: no especifique.. cuando lo coloco asi y coloco de 1 a 8 digitos me lanza el error "cedula no debe ser mayor a 8.".. es decir.. q ni siquiera colocando solo 3 digitos me lanza el correcto, puesto que el verdadero error la cantidad MINIMA es 6. o me equivoco?

Comment: el número mínimo sería 100000 o 000000?

Comment: deberia ser 100000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basándome en los comentarios debería ser así la sintaxis de `min` y `max` para que funcione con valores mínimo de 100000 y máximo de 99999999:

```
'cedula' =>  'numeric|required|unique:personas|min:100000|max:99999999',
```

Comment: efectivamente, gracias. Creia que funcionaba igual que con los de caracteres. Creia que se referia a cantidad de digitos. Disculpen mi ignorancia. Gracias de verdad.

Answer (score 1):

OTRA ALTERNATIVA sería que usaras

```
'cedula' =>  'numeric|required|unique:personas|digits_between:6,8',
```

Funciona para validar la cantidad de números insertados en un campo.

En este caso dice que el campo debe contener entre 6  y 8 dígitos.

Answer (score 0):

segun la documentacion:

> between:min,max The field under validation must have a size between
>   the given min and max. Strings, numerics, and files are evaluated in
>   the same fashion as the size rule.

entonces seria asi:

> 'cedula' => 'required|numeric|unique:personas|integer|between:6,8',

creo que esto tambien pueda funcionar:
Editado 1:

> 'cedula' => 'required|numeric|unique:personas|integer|min:000000|max:99999999',

nota: ninguno de las dos soluciones no fue probado por mi persona, pruebalo y comenta si funciono alguna.

Comment: con el between me dice "cedula tiene que estar entre 6 - 8.".
y con min6 y max8 me dice "cedula no debe ser mayor a 8."

ambos los pruebo con la cantidad de digitos del 1 al 8 y me da el mismo error. el problema se elimina si quito "integer y numeric"..

Comment: @PabloContreras quita solo numeric

Comment: me da el mismo error :(

Comment: hermano.. la solucion me la dio Shaz . Gracias de todas formas :D

Comment: @PabloContreras lo que pasaba es que no estamos tratando con la cantidad de digitos

Comment: si, ignoraba eso. Ni se me ocurrio en lo mas minimo que pudiera ser eso, e intentaba de todas las manera pero nada que encontraba la solucion, por eso pregunte aca y resulta que era una tonteria. Mil gracias :D